# Which is faster for retrieval and setting?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

In doing a retrieval from a SQL or MySql database, which would be faster, 5 ish boolean columns or one column as an integer bit flag?

Comment: Your application architecture is almost certainly going to be vastly more important than this potential micro-optimization.

Comment: Exactly - don't waste your time continuously packing (and extracting) five boolean values from an `INT` column. Use five `BOOLEAN` columns (storage size: 1 byte each, or 5 bytes per row) instead of one hard-to-manage `INT` column (storage size: 4 bytes per row). Or use a `CHAR(1)` and store `Y` or `N` - whatever is easiest for you to understand.

Comment: Packing them all into an integer bit flag kind of defeats the purpose of the database. Don't pollute your queries or application logic with storage implementation details. Modern databases are actually quite efficient with storing booleans, so you should worry more about modeling the data in a query-friendly, human-readable shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach to dealing with "flag" columns:

**Case 1:** I have a limited number of flags/attributes that will not change significantly. I use booleans because these are low maintenance and (on any database worth its salt) very efficient. In fact, on SQL Server if you have 8 or fewer bit/boolean columns, [they will occupy 1 byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). With 16 bits you'll have 2 bytes, and so on.

I *might* be able to make a slight optimization by manually packing them into an integer, but only in certain use cases (say, if I want to control the specific grouping), and it wouldn't be a very portable solution across different database engines. So, in 99% of cases I avoid that line of thinking.

**Case 2:** I have an unbounded number of flags/attributes. Perhaps the number is 5 right now, but there is nothing stopping it from eventually becoming 100 or 1000. In this case, I use a more "relational" approach by storing a separate table of flags and linking them with a join table.

Comment: In Case 2, would forcing the database to do a join with a table of bit flags going to be faster than simply receiving a single integer and using bit masking to get the same data?

Comment: Case 2 is built around the idea that the flags/attributes would exist as data rows in the table, and could be added/removed using INSERT/DELETE statements instead of updating the schema. It's less about it being "faster" in terms of app performance and more about it being "faster" in terms of the developer's productivity. Again, really only makes sense when the list of flags is totally unbounded and expected to change a lot over time.

Comment: Excellent Answer, and very enlightening.  As pointed out earlier, this won't impact performance in a Huge way, however the project I'm dealing with Involves connecting to many different databases that all require any schema changes individually.  That makes case 2 an Ideal solution given that it would involve a single change that would never need to be repeated.